# Hilbert space operator that takes all orthonormal sequences to strong null-sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Say that we have Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ and an operator $T : \mathcal{H}_1\to \mathcal{H}_2$ such that for any orthonormal sequence $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset \mathcal{H}_1$, $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \|T(e_n)\| = 0$$ It's not obvious to me that $T$ is a bounded operator, even in the case where $\mathcal{H}_1$ is separable, although I'm pretty sure that it must be true [given that we can prove that $T$ is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66329/a-question-on-compact-operators#comment481803_66329), which therefore implies that $T$ is bounded (although proving that $T$ is compact seems like overkill). Is there a way to show the boundedness of $T$ without first showing the compactness of $T$? Thanks for your time.

Comment: If an operator T is unbounded, then there should be an orthonormal sequence $\{e_n\}_n$ for which $\|Te_n\| > n$. Indeed, having constructed $e_1, \ldots, e_k$, we still must have that $T$ is unbounded on the orthocomplement of the span of the $e_1, \ldots, e_k$.

Comment: Why should such a sequence be orthonormal? As far as I can tell, we only have that it lies on the unit sphere.

Comment: After choosing $e_i$, for $i = 1, \ldots, k$ such that $\|Te_i\| > i$, you can consider the linear span $S_k$ of the $k$ already chosen vectors. Then consider the orthocomplement $M_k = S_k^\perp$. By definition, every vector in $M_k$ is orthogonal to the vectors $e_1, \ldots, e_k$. Since $T$ is unbounded on the whole space, it is also unbounded on $M_k$ and hence there is a unit norm vector $e_{k+1} \in M_k$ such that $\|Te_{k+1}\|> k+1$.

Comment: I understand. And $T$ is unbounded on the orthocomplement of $\mathrm{span}(\{e_1, \ldots, e_k\})$ because it's unbounded on $\mathrm{span}(\{e_1\})^{\mathrm{T}}$ by the reverse triangle inequality, and then on $\mathrm{span}(\{e_1, \ldots, e_k\})^{\mathrm{T}}$ by induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Malman explained, the boundedness of $T$ follows by contradiction. Moreover, it suffices to assume that $T$ takes orthonormal sequences to *bounded* sequences. Suppose $T$ is unbounded. First pick $e_1$ such that $\|Te_1\|>1$.

After some orthonormal vectors $e_1,\dots,e_n$ with $\|Te_j\|>j$ have been selected, consider the spaces $M=\operatorname{span}(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ and $N=M^\perp$. Since $M$ is finite-dimensional, $T$ is bounded on $M$. If $T$ was also bounded on $N$, it would be bounded on $M+N$, i.e., all of $\mathcal H_1$, by the triangle inequality. Hence, $T$ is unbounded on $N$, which allows us to choose $e_{n+1}\in N$ with $\|Te_{n+1}\|>n+1$, and thus the process continues indefinitely.

The result is an orthonormal sequence $\{e_n\}$ such that $\|Te_n\|\to \infty$, contradicting the assumption.